# g++ special handling of printf

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

Anyone knows why the following code works under g++ 4.7.2?  If I change the name `printf` to another name such as `f`, it has compiler error saying constexpr can't contain non-const function calls (which I think is the correct behavior).

```
[hidden]$ cat d.cpp 
extern "C" { extern int printf(const char* s, ...); }
constexpr int g() { return printf(""), 0; }
template <int N> struct X { const static int value = N; };
int n = X<g()>::value;
[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 -c d.cpp
[hidden]$ g++ -v |& tail -1
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC)
```

Note I don't include any header files.

Comment: why it shouldn't work?

Comment: As I said, if I change the `printf` to any other name, it has the compiler error.  So generally it shouldn't work.  Here it works only because gcc has special handling for a name called `printf`.  This is weird.

Comment: This is probably a bug, g++ 4.6 as well as clang++ 3.1 reject this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf()` is handled as a builtin function by GCC/g++ in many cases (though I think this behavior is still a bug). From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html:

> The ISO C90 functions ... `printf` ... are all recognized as built-in functions unless `-fno-builtin` is specified (or `-fno-builtin-function` is specified for an individual function)

You get the correct diagnostic if you use the `-fno-builtin` option.

The bug appears to be fixed in 4.8.0.

Comment: Good to hear it is fixed in 4.8.0

Comment: `gcc 4.8.2` still allows `printf` and other [builtins in a constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176777/why-can-i-call-a-non-constexpr-function-inside-a-constexpr-function). My gut says this is not strictly conformant unless they document this as an extension.

Answer (score -1):

I think `stdio.h` is included by default

I try it with `puts` and works for me [gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)]

```
extern "C" { extern int puts(const char* s); }
constexpr int g() { return puts(""), 0; }
template <int N> struct X { const static int value = N; };
int n = X<g()>::value;
```

**Edit:**

@Keith Thompson

Before I wrote "included by default" I tried the code below without `#include <stdio.h>`. It compiles with some warnings but runs - so (for some reason) `printf`, `scanf`, `puts` works without `#include <stdio.h>`. Maybe `stdio.h` is not included by default, maybe library with `printf`, `scanf`, `puts` is linked by default.

```
int main()
{
    char one;

    printf("Hello ");
    scanf("%c", &one);
    puts("world!");
}
```

Comment: I don't believe *any* header is included by default. Try declaring `FILE *foo` without `#include <stdio.h>`; you'll find that the identifier `FILE` is not visible.