# Why can I call a non-constexpr function inside a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, constexpr, side-effects

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr int f()
{
    return printf("a side effect!\n");
}

int main()
{
    char a[f()];
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof a);
}
```

I would have expected the compiler to complain about the call to `printf` inside `f`, because `f` is supposed to be `constexpr`, but `printf` is not. Why does the program [compile and print 15](https://ideone.com/QNL5u8)?

Comment: clang `3.5` gives me an error: `note: non-constexpr function 'printf' cannot be used in a constant expression`

Comment: Could it be that your compiler allows VLAs? This fails on GC 4.8.2 with reasonable compiler flags. `error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]`

Comment: @GabiMe Whatever compiler ideone uses :)

Comment: On gcc 4.8.2 with `-pedantic` this gives an error. Apparently, gcc treats this as a VLA and never tries to check if this is really `constexpr`. Tring to use `f()` as a non-type template argument will fail.

Comment: @pmr I would say it does check, and it finds isn't `constexpr`. Then it complains about VLAs, because that is something it supports by default.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think this boils down to: When should an invalid `constexpr` be rejected: (a) always, like clang does, (b) when its compile-time evaluation is required?

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree. `clang` seems to be over-eager to reject this and this should probably be a warning instead of an error. It should be an error when `f()` is used as a `constexpr`. Unfortunately, I cannot easily back this up with a quote.

Comment: @pmr Actually, I think you are right. I thought calling `f()` was legal in a non-constexpr context. I have to check this though.

Comment: @pmr It looks like a bug in GCC. If I replace the call to `printf` with one to `int foo() {return 42;}` it fails to compile. It should do the same with `printf` because neither is `constexpr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Maybe this is happening because `strlen` in GCC on a character literal is `constexpr` and GCC substitutes `printf` with `puts` (or `puts`+`strlen` if you consume the return value) if the format string contains no format specifiers. So apart from the obvious side effect, one could _believe_ that this is a mighty fine `constexpr` function.

Comment: @Damon hmmm, I don't think the compiler is allowed to do that ... and if we use this `constexpr int  x = f();` in `gcc` it produces an error.

Comment: @pmr it depends in this case the standard says it is ill-formed and no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I agree that it is certainly illegal, but I can see how the compiler might _believe_ that it is, due to those substitutions. `constexpr int x = strlen("foo");` compiles just fine, and if you disassemble the binary, you never find a single call to `strlen` anywhere, only the literal (assuming you use it, so it isn't optimized out). Ironically, this is **not** true for built-in macros such as `__func__`, which, to you and me, are quite obviously `constexpr`, but the compiler will claim that they're not.

Comment: @Damon huh, that is good for thought, if you use `-fno-builtin` these all become errors in `gcc`. So that makes more sense, I still think the compiler is not allowed to do this though.

Comment: @Damon I posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182432/gcc-considering-builtins-of-non-constant-expression-functions-to-be-constant-exp) on whether `gcc` is allowed to do this or not.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Feel free to retag.

Comment: I know this is late, but generally I rely on using `std::array<int, f()> a;` to test constant expressions rather than VLA's. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f83344965403611d)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect some new information and some information I should have added back then but forgot to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The program is *ill-formed* and requires no diagnostic according to the [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `7.1.5` *The constexpr specifier* paragraph *5* which says:

> For a constexpr function, if no function argument values exist such
>   that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant
>   expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

and provides the following example:

```
constexpr int f(bool b)
  { return b ? throw 0 : 0; } // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); } // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

and section `5.19` paragraph *2* says:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   [...]

and includes:

> — an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a
>   literal class or a  constexpr function [ Note: Overload resolution
>   (13.3) is applied as usual —end note ];

We would probably prefer a diagnostic in this case, it could just be an oversight, I have a bug report for a similar situation where `gcc` does not produce an error but we would probably like it to: [Is the compiler allowed leeway in what it considers undefined behavior in a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502017/is-the-compiler-allowed-leeway-in-what-it-considers-undefined-behavior-in-a-cons).

**Update**

Using the `-fno-builtin` flag will cause `gcc` to generate the following error:

```
 error: call to non-constexpr function 'int printf(const char*, ...)'
 return printf("a side effect!\n");
                                 ^
```

So `gcc` does consider this *ill-formed* it is just  ignores it when it is using the builtin version of `printf`.

Although somewhat inconsistently using the `-pedantic` produces the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]
 char a[f()];
           ^
```

Note that using `f()` to initialized a *constexpr* variable:

```
constexpr int x = f() ;
```

does generate an error:

```
error: 'printf(((const char*)"a side effect!\012"))' is not a constant expression
```

Note that additionally in the more general case a compiler is not allowed mark standard library functions as *constexpr* [unless explicitly allowed by the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27744079/1708801).

Answer (score 0):

The program is legal since C++23.

C++23 allows you to mark (almost) any function as `constexpr`, even if it's impossible to evaluate at compile-time. In your case the function will run at runtime. You will only get an error if you try to *force* it to run at compile-time, e.g. by assigning the result to a `constexpr` variable.