# Can a constexpr function call a function that returns void?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is what I would like to do:

```
void g() {
    std::cout << "smth1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "smth2" << std::endl;
}

constexpr bool f() {return g(), true;}
```

The compiler (`gcc` version 4.8.2) is not happy with this, since `g` is not `constexpr`. Is it possible to get around this problem?

Comment: What would *you* expect from calling a function with some side effect (producing output in this case) during a compile-time evaluation?

Comment: @5gon12eder When I write `if (f()) {...}`, I would like the compiler to get rid of that branch during the optimization phase, since f() is guaranteed at compile-time to return `true`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning So you want the compiler to execute the side effects of `g` but eliminate the branch?

Comment: @interjay True, but this restriction was lifted in C++14 while the conceptual problem remains.

Comment: @MarkB What's wrong with that? Isn't it known at compile-time that f() returns `true`? So, if the client writes `if (!f())`, can't the compiler know that the condition will not be satisfied?

Comment: @5gon12eder My comment refers to the fact that the function had two different return types specified.

Comment: @5gon12eder The function referred to in the title refers to `g`, which does return `void`.

Comment: Note, you may get [gcc to accept non-constexpr function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22176777/1708801) that have builtins but it is still ill-formed and not portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of constexpr is that it can be fully expanded at compile-time. There is no possible way that the compiler can put runtime side effects (using `cout`) into what is effectively a more complex compile-time constant. Put another way: No actual function call will be made at runtime for `constexpr` functions!

Luckily the solution is easy!

Change `f` to `constexpr bool f() { return true;}`

and your conditional to:

```
g();
if(f())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In my case, `g` is a template argument. I wanted to allow `g` to return either `void` or `bool`. I tag-dispatch on the return type of `g`. The code I showed is for the case when `g` returns `void`. When `g` returns `bool`, I return `g()`, which is then used in a conditional statement. I wanted to avoid branching in the case when `g` returns `void`.

Comment: The reply does answer the question as it was asked, so accepting it. I will ask another question that will provide all the relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

Any evaluation of a function called during the evaluation of a constant expression must not have any side effects. In C++11, the rules are actually much stricter, allowing only a single `return` statement as function body but that's not relevant to this question.

The compiler is not entitled to remove any code from a `constexpr` function in order to make it comply. It is your responsibility to not write such code in the first place.

However, it is okay to have code with side effects inside a `constexpr` function if the control flow during static evaluation never passes through it.

This is valid C++11.

```
void g() { std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl; }
constexpr bool f(const bool p = false) { return p ? (g(), false) : true; }
```

And you may call `f` like this.

```
constexpr auto x = f();  // ok
```

Because `p` is `false` at compile-time, the compiler need not evaluate the call to `g`. At run-time, you may call `f` with either argument just as if it were not a `constexpr` function.

```
f(false);  // ok
f(true);   // ok, produces output at run-time
```

What you cannot do is evaluate it in a constant expression with the parameter set to `true`.

```
constexpr auto x = f(true);  // compile-time error
```

Of course, this example is contrived beyond any restrictions and you should simply write

```
constexpr bool f() noexcept { return true; }
```

or use a variable

```
constexpr auto toggle = true;
```

if this is all you need.